# jQuery to change style sheet (like a theme switcher), doesn't load CSS in IE

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

So the page is here: http://www.sumsy.com/testing/1/login.html

It works in FF, but no IE.

The problem is:

Click on Change Theme, select the second box(blue box), the site should switch to a new theme,

However, in IE, it just doesn't load any CSS style. I did some debugging. The style sheet link `attr` is actually changed.

Can you guys please shed some light?

You can see the JS (mainly theme-switcher.js) and HTML code from view source. If you need me to paste the code here, please let me know.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing it in? They each have their peculiar quirks, to put it kindly.

Comment: having this issue in both IE6 and IE7

Answer (score 2):

Updating `link` elements dynamically has highly variable behaviour.  I found the same issue when (for some crazy reason) I wanted to dynamically change favicon links.  The best solution is to remove the old link and replace it with a new one:

```
$('#active-theme').replaceWith($('<link>', {
    id: 'active-theme',
    href: 'themes/' + get_cookie + '/_css/main.css',
    type: 'text/css',
    rel: 'stylesheet' 
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I tried with your code, it still doesnt work in IE6, 7

Comment: Your page doesn't really work for me either (in Chrome), since URLs like http://www.sumsy.com/testing/1/themes/theme03/_css/main.css don't actually work.

Comment: oh, since I only have 2 styles set up so far. Please just try the first 2 boxes in the change theme tab. so only themes/style1/_css/main.css or themes/style2/_css/main.css would load

Comment: It works in FF. but not sure why it doesnt work in chrome or IE. worst thing is, it doesnt give me any error. so hard to find out whats wrong.

Comment: Looks like the issue is in main.css actually it import the code from other css files as well. looks like IE doesnt do the import after link is changed by jquery
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('styles.css');
@import url('layout.css');
@import url('widgets.css');
@import url('widgets.old.css');

Comment: If I change it to href: 'themes/' + get_cookie + '/_css/layout.css', and it doesnt import code from other files. then it works fine. Is that IE bug?